# minMaxLoc datatype

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision

I have been stumped by this for quite some time. could you please help me to know, what datatype does the minMaxLoc() in Opencv consider, while finding the max, min vlaues of a Mat variable? I got a certain value from the function, but I have no idea wat that value actually represents, and in what data type?

```
    Laplacian(src_gray,dst,ddepth,kernel_size,scale,delta,BORDER_DEFAULT);
    minMaxLoc(dst,&min,&estimate,&minLoc,&maxLoc,noArray());
```

The value of 'estimate' is somewhere around 1000's, while if I try to access the value of 'dst' Mat variable, using

```
    dst.at<datatype>(k,l)
```

Am getting vague values, starting from 124, 125 for uchar, to 2,xxx,xxx,xxx if I use long int. What is the value actually given by the minMaxLoc function? Please help me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

min and estimate should be of type double and I would imagine they are correct.  The issue is probably with you accessing

```
dst.at<datatype>(k,l)
```

As Abhishek Thakur mentioned, the output depends on your input.  If you are ever confused about the type of a matrix you can look at dst.type() which returns an integer corresponding to the list defined in [types_c.h](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/types_c.h?rev=3837) starting at line 557.  The definitions for single channel types or "depths" are

```
#define CV_8U   0
#define CV_8S   1 
#define CV_16U  2
#define CV_16S  3
#define CV_32S  4
#define CV_32F  5
#define CV_64F  6
```

You can see the formula used to calculate the other type identifiers on line 573

```
#define CV_CN_SHIFT   3
#define CV_DEPTH_MAX  (1 << CV_CN_SHIFT)

#define CV_MAT_DEPTH_MASK       (CV_DEPTH_MAX - 1)
#define CV_MAT_DEPTH(flags)     ((flags) & CV_MAT_DEPTH_MASK)

#define CV_MAKETYPE(depth,cn) (CV_MAT_DEPTH(depth) + (((cn)-1) << CV_CN_SHIFT))
```

for example

```
#define CV_8UC4 CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U,4)
```

has type

```
0+((4-1) << 3) == 24
```

so for a 4 channel uchar image, type() will return 24.  From the above you can see that the depth of a type is represented by the last 3 bits of the type integer.  If all you want is the depth (you don't care how many channels it has) you can get that directly with dst.depth()

Comment: @Hammer I know this might sound silly, but where Can I find the definition for those in built variables? I tried searching, but am slightly out of time. If you could please help me, I will be glad. variables such as CV_16S etc. Wat datatypes do they represent?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan the U means unsigned, the S means signed, the F means float.  the number is how many bits are involved.  CV_16S means a 16 bit signed integer

Comment: @Hammer If I use double as the datatype in dst.at<double>, it is not working. returns me no value. Could you please tell me why, if you know the reason?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan is dst a CV_64F?

Comment: @hammer it is CV_16S.  while accessing its value, its returning me NaN.

Comment: @hammer I used long double, and the values are extremely small. however, the minMaxLoc gives me a relatively very large value. This has always and is still confusing me. Please help me.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan when you say dst.at<double> you are telling dst to interpret its contents as a double (CV_64f) and then return a specific element to you.  There is no telling what it will return if you do that because as you said it actually contains CV_16S, a 16 bit signed integer

Comment: @hammer Then I feel I have exhausted my options, cuz int and long int dint do much of help as well. Defining dft as CV_64F will solve the problem?

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan int and long int do not have well defined bit lengths.  It is likely though that your int was 32 bits and your long int was 32 or 64.  For 16 bits you could try short but your best bet when you care about size like this is to use an int with an explicit length like int16_t

Answer (score 3):

[Hammer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14365886/433685) answer is very clear and it shows you a nice tips: always check the datatypes and be aware of `types_c.h`, check it out every time you want!

Anyway, minMaxLoc returns a double but it already do the cast for you. If you give a uchar Mat objects as input array it will set the 2 double variables as double in the range 0-255 (the uchar range!).

See this example:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/) {

    double m, M;
    Point p_min, p_max;
    Mat img;

    // let's do with uchar Mat
    img = (Mat_<uchar>(3,3) << 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,255); 
    cout << img << endl;
    minMaxLoc(img, &m, &M, &p_min, &p_max);
    cout << "min: " << m << " at " << p_min << endl;
    cout << "max: " << M << " at " << p_max << endl;
    cout << (int)img.at<uchar>(p_max.y, p_max.x) << endl; // cast to int otherwise cout will print an ASCII (uchar)

    // now with float Mat
    img = (Mat_<float>(3,3) << 0.1f,1.2f,2,3000.2f,4,5,6,7,255); 
    cout << img << endl;
    minMaxLoc(img, &m, &M, &p_min, &p_max);
    cout << "min: " << m << " at " << p_min << endl;
    cout << "max: " << M << " at " << p_max << endl;
    cout << img.at<float>(p_max.y, p_max.x) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

now, in the code you posted you define the destination type in the `ddepth`. You can specify `ddepth` as a opencv constant datatypes, like:

```
ddepth = CV_8UC1
```

in this case the cv::Laplacian will return a uchar Mat.

So, be always aware of what kind of data are you handling. If you are working with colour image you'd probabilly better to use `Mat::at<Scalar>()`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what value u want. For a gray scale image if you input a Mat with uchar data type you will get a value between 0 to 255.