# The call imshow() in OpenCV is not creating any output

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, v4l2

I am trying to read data from an industrial camera using the V4l linux driver and C++. I would like to display the result using the OpenCV. I read the buffer, create an Mat object, which actually contains values in range 0...255.

The problem seems to be the imshow() call. When commenting this line out, an actual window without an image is displayed. Once uncommented no window is diplayed and also no output in terminal after this line is shown. I am not able to find a solution on my own, all examples I found look the same as my code to me.

Here is the code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include <libv4l2.h>
#include <libv4l1.h>
#include <linux/videodev2.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h> 

#define BUFFERSIZE 357120 // 744 * 480

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
int cameraHandle, i;
unsigned char pictureBuffer[BUFFERSIZE];
char cameraDevice[] = "/dev/video0";
struct v4l2_control V4L2_control;

/* open camera device */
if (( cameraHandle = v4l1_open(cameraDevice, O_RDONLY)) == -1 ){
    printf("Unable to open the camera");
    return -1;
}

// disable auto exposure
V4L2_control.id = V4L2_CID_EXPOSURE_AUTO;
V4L2_control.value = V4L2_EXPOSURE_SHUTTER_PRIORITY;
ioctl(cameraHandle, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &V4L2_control);
// set exposure time
V4L2_control.id = V4L2_CID_EXPOSURE_ABSOLUTE;
V4L2_control.value = 2;
ioctl(cameraHandle, VIDIOC_S_CTRL, &V4L2_control);

// get 5 pictures to warm up the camera
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++){
    v4l1_read(cameraHandle, pictureBuffer, BUFFERSIZE);
}

// show pictures
Mat mat = Mat(744, 480, CV_8UC3, (void*)pictureBuffer);
cout << "M = " << endl << " " << mat << endl << endl; // display the image data

namedWindow("imagetest", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
imshow("imagetest", mat);
waitKey(30);

cout << "test output" << endl;

//clenup
v4l1_close(cameraHandle);
destroyWindow("imagetest");

return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

Well, after running the code in terminal instead of ecipse I saw a *segmentation fault* Even commenting everything behind the

```
cout << "M = " << endl << " " << mat << endl << endl;
```

line gives me this error.

Comment: Is image data corrupted? Have you tried imwrite to test whether image is taken properly from the camera? For me kinda low-level image initaliazation from byte data. Are you sure out image data from function v4l1_read is compatibiile with Mat constructor?

Comment: I am not sure, the cap() method from opencv is not supportd by the camera. The guvcview program shows me, that it utilises the Y800 grayscale format. Changing the image format to CV_8UC1 when creating the mat object brings improvements. No segmentation faults and the code runs through, but the image window apperas only for a milisecond and disappears again.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem lied in the wrong file format. CV_8UC1 or CV_8U instead of CV_8UC3 brought and an output. The difference between those formats is described here: [In OpenCV, what's the difference between CV_8U and CV_8UC1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543420/in-opencv-whats-the-difference-between-cv-8u-and-cv-8uc1)