# OpenCV CV_8UC3 to CV_8UC1

Tags: java, opencv

My image is of type `CV_8UC3` (it is a grayscale image) and I need it as `CV_8UC1`.
How can I do the transformation? I already tried

```
Mat right = new Mat(rectRight.width(), rectRight.height(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
rectRight.convertTo(right, CvType.CV_8UC1,255,0);
```

But it still gives me a 3-channel image.

RectLeft is the rectified version of this image:

```
Imgproc.undistort(Highgui.imread(images[0], Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), undist_left, cameraMatrix, distCoeff);
```

The rectification is done using this part of code:

```
Mat rectLeft = new Mat();
Imgproc.initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix, distCoeff, R1, newCameraMatrix_left, left.size(), CvType. CV_32FC1, map1_left, map2_left);        
Imgproc.remap(left, rectLeft, map1_left, map2_left, Imgproc.INTER_LANCZOS4);
```

The rectified image (and its partner of the right camera) should be used in

```
StereoBM stereoAlgo = new StereoBM();
stereoAlgo.compute(left, right, disparity);
```

But there is an exception which says that both input images should be of type `CV_8UC1` but I've checked and `rectLeft.type()` gives me a 16. (I guess this is `CV_8UC1`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you probably want  a grayscale conversion for StereoBM :

```
Imgproc.cvtConvert(src,dst,Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#cvtColor(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20int)

(you can't change/reduce the number of channels with Mat.convertTo(), only the depth)

Answer (score 3):

No, 16 is `CV_8UC3`:

```
~  python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 11 2012, 20:14:37)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-418.0.60)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.CV_8UC1
0
>>> cv2.CV_8UC3
16
>>>
```

You have to convert it into grayscale:

```
cvtColor(imageIn, imageOut, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

From the references:

> void Mat::convertTo(Mat& m, int rtype, double alpha=1, double beta=0) const
>
> rtype – The desired destination matrix type, or rather, **the depth
>   (since the number of channels will be the same with the source one)**.
>   If rtype is negative, the destination matrix will have the same type
>   as the source.

or `split` the channels and take only one of them, or convert to binary images using `threshold`

#### EDIT:

For a complete answer on how types (like 8UC1 etc) are build in opencv see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364563/minmaxloc-datatype/14365886#14365886).

For converting to a grayscale.. google it, it's full of good resources. Remember the references [The basic image container](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html)