# What do the numbers returned by OpenCV's VideoCapture::get(CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT) mean?

Tags: opencv

The OpenCV function [VideoCapture::get](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html#videocapture-get) returns "the specified VideoCapture property". We can ask for the frame's format using the property `CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT`.

The frames are Mat objects and from the docs ([here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html)) Mat "represents an n-dimensional dense numerical single-channel or multi-channel array" but does not seem to include a format enum.

How do I understand which format each of the numbers returned by VideoCapture::get(CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT) are? How do I map them into image format options?

Comment: Looking at the [code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/d861c03366a0883b2a84ff4a2de06e523891373d/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp#L1638), it appears to be the `Mat` datatype code -- e.g. `CV_8UC1` [and similar](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga9d2ee1a8334733dea7482a47a88e0f87)

Comment: Also https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_gphoto2.cpp#L543 https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_mjpeg_decoder.cpp#L775

Comment: @DanMašek, how do I translate things like `CV_8UC1` or say `CV_32SC` into things I understand like RGB32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DanMašek comments above it is the Mat's datatype code, e.g. `CV_8UC1`, as can be seen, for example, in the code [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/d861c03366a0883b2a84ff4a2de06e523891373d/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp#L1638):

```cplusplus
case CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT:
   return CV_MAKETYPE(CV_8U, capture->frame.nChannels);
```

(with the `#define` for those type synonyms [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/de0/group__core__utils.html#ga9d2ee1a8334733dea7482a47a88e0f87).)

@Hammer explains these synomyms further in a comment to his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14365886/575530): "the U means unsigned, the S means signed, the F means float. the number is how many bits are involved. CV_16S means a 16 bit signed integer". Further to that the "Cn" means the number of channels, e.g. C3 for RGB.